# How to run my react app in Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

I have this react app I want to dockerize. But the problem is, even though I tried, it doesn't work. **But it works pretty well locally**

This is how the current directories look like:

```
docker-compose.yaml
frontend_v2
   - node_modules
   - public
   - src
       - <react jsx files>
   - Dockerfile
   - package.json
   - package-lock.json
```

So this is the content of the above `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

# Add rest of the client code
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And I am using a `docker-compose.yml` to spin up the container, and this is how it looks like:
This is in the root directory.

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend_v2
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      # - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend_v2/src:/app/src
    ports:
      - 80:3000
```

Problem I am facing is, even though the container is running I get the below error **(which I don't get I run locally)**

When i try

`docker logs <exited-container-id>` i get this below output

```
> cyberhr-rv18.0.4@0.1.0 start /app
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  /app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server (version: 3.10.3) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack-dev-server in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack-dev-server.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cyberhr-rv18.0.4@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cyberhr-rv18.0.4@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-18T08_32_25_268Z-debug.log
```

[Update]

Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "cyberhr-rv18.0.4",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "3d-force-graph": "^1.60.11",
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.26.1",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.5.1",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.35",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.7.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-tsne": "^0.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "d3-dsv": "^1.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "evergreen-ui": "^4.27.4",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "material-dashboard-react": "^1.8.0",
    "mdbreact": "4.25.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-chat-popup": "^1.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.0.1",
    "react-force-graph": "^1.32.1",
    "react-full-screen": "^0.2.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-nvd3": "^0.5.7",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.4",
    "react-pure-grid": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-step-wizard": "^5.3.2",
    "react-table": "^7.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.8",
    "react-window-size": "^1.2.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "tabler-react": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "three": "latest",
    "tsne-js": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-to-print": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please post your package.json as well. Also, you should copy package-lock.json into the container too before doing the install to have the same pre-conditions as your local install.

Comment: Hi, I added `package.json`

Comment: webpack-dev-server is not listed there, so unless it is a sub-dependency of some other package, it doesn't get installed. Search for `webpack-dev-server` in your package-lock.json and see if it shows up (and which package it gets installed with), otherwise you might have installed it manually or globally at some point (`npm install -g`).

Comment: Have you tried the procedure 1.2.3.4 in the log output?  You might want to document that.  I note you are ok on #3, the dev webserver doesn't appear in your posted `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, I tried every procedure mentioned in the log output. Sill getting the same error. #3 is automatically satisfied because because i don't have that dependency in the `package.json` @Paul

Comment: If you do `npm list -g --depth=0` you get a tree structure of all global npm packages you have installed, maybe webpack-dev-server is in there.

Comment: @jishi there are couple of places `webpack-dev-server` in the package-lock.json.

Comment: @ToRrent That's why they ask you to delete package-lock.json and `rm -rf node_modules`.   Those get rebuilt by `npm install`

Comment: No it is not in the global package @jishi

Comment: @Paul I did delete `package-lock.json` many times along with the `node_modules` and still get the same error when i freshly install packages with `npm install`. It works fine in locally. But when i try to dockerize it, this problem comes

Comment: Is there a workaround guys? Please help me :)

Comment: Ok, reading the output, it says you actually have version 3.10.3 but need 3.11.0, so I assume that you have some version discrepancy amongst your packages. 

It could also be a version discrepancy with node/npm that is causing this difference in dependency tree. If your package-lock.json works locally, it should work in the docker (but you need to copy that as well on you Dockerfile). 

Otherwise, try to version match your docker node/npm version with the corresponding local version by using a specific version rather than `latest`

Comment: Okay I will COPY the package-lock.json file as well to the Dockerfile and I will get back to you if there is a probelm.

Comment: OK so my approach to Docker is more minimalist.  I wouldn't do the npm install on docker. I just copy everything in and it runs.  For you, this means running `npm i `in the `/app` directory work on your machine and testing it there to see if it works.  Then delete lines 3 and 4 from `Dockerfile` and build again.

Comment: @Paul is copying node_modules to the container a good thing rather than installing with `npm install`, Is the problem with my `Dockerfile` ? Can you give a suggestion?

Comment: Copying the node_modules folder is normally a bad idea, because it might break if you are running different envs (windows, mac, linux). A dependency installed in MacOS which has native code won't work in a linux container, for instance.

Comment: @ToRRent I think your existing Dockerfile creates a bad tree for your app.  One solution is to build a working tree outside of docker, and then copy that whole thing into the container.

Comment: @jishi That's true.  But if its a container for a specific cloud deployment system, it might always run whatever they've contracted.

Comment: @jishi Also, the issue you mention would seem to require `npm install` to run in a shell script in every instance; not in the `RUN` commands of the build script.

Comment: @Paul can you give provide an answer with the correct structure for the `Dockerfile` ? As you have commented below in following answer, you said my `package-lock.json` is overwritten. Can you provide a solution?

Comment: I'll post a dockerfile I use.

Comment: @paul The RUN commands are invoked on the template container, so it is running on the actual base image in question, be it glibc based debian derivate or a musl C alpine image, it makes a difference when installing native modules.

Comment: @jishi what is your solution on this? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you are copying the same package-lock.json file that you use to install deps locally, to make sure you have the same dependency tree in your container as you do locally.

`COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/`

Then, make sure that you are matching the same node/npm version as you run locally (replace 12 with the major version you are running, be it 10, 12, 14 or whatever):

`FROM node:12`

Each node version is bundled with a specific npm version (latest 12 version comes with npm 6.14.6), you can find the bundled NPM version int he changelogs, https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/doc/changelogs

Additionally, instead of running `npm install`, you might wanna run `npm ci` in the container. The latter skips any checks for discrepancy between the lock file and your package.json file and just installs the locked dependency tree, which is not only faster, but will also match your local dep tree exactly.

EDIT:

In addition, this line:

`COPY . /app`

Would also overwrite node_modules unless you have ignored it via .dockerignore or similar.

Easiest would probably be to add a `.dockerignore` file to the same folder as your Dockerfile and add lines stating:

```
.git
node_modules
```

The complete Dockerfile would look like this:

```
# Use whatever version you are running locally (see node -v)
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies (you are already in /app)
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

# Add rest of the client code
# .dockerignore needs to skip node_modules
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Oh, yeah.  His `package-lock` from the `npm install` in the container is being overwritten by the full app copy later in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: That doesn't really matter, it's what's in the package files when invoking `npm install` that matters.

Comment: @jishi can you provide the structure of the `Dockerfile` please?

Comment: @ToRrent Added a sample Dockerfile, but remember to create a .dockerignore file.

Comment: Do you find any problems with my `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with your docker-compose.yml, but if you now get the same fault locally it means that the dependency tree has changed. If you can restore a working package-lock.json and use that you should be fine. Just make sure to copy it to the container before the installation as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

So here

```
# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install
```

at the end of these steps you will have a NEW `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder in the container build environment.

But then the posted `Dockerfile` has:

```
# Add rest of the client code
COPY . /app
```

and quite possibly -- WHAMMO! -- they're gone.  Whatever OLD `package-lock.json` file or `node_modules` directory was in the . folder on the build machine will overwrite the ./app folder in the container -- including those NEW files just created in the container.  Or perhaps end up with some unholy mix of both in the `node_modules` directory.

I take a different approach.  I get everything working as I want it, and use this `Dockerfile` that lives in the directory with the source code:

```
FROM node:alpine  # as of 2020-09 this runs node 14; also uses sh not bash
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
USER node
EXPOSE 8888   # change this to the port(s) where your app listens
CMD [ "node", "./index.js" ]
```

This is copied from a production system that relies on Google Cloud Build to build the container for launch on GCP.  Therefore, the environment on the execution system is going to be Linux, the same as on my developer system.
If you are going cross-platform development, this obviously won't work sometimes.

Comment: How can I make sure the `node_modules` is going to copy as well? There shouldn't be any .gitingore or .dockerginore files as well right? or?

Comment: `.gitignore` is not a problem, but `.dockerignore` should be examined carefully.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right about the overwrite of node_modules, and I think it merges the folders.

Comment: Shouldn't `WORKDIR` put before `COPY` ?

Comment: In this case I'm not sure that matters.  This script is copied from my known-working system.

Comment: I removed both `package-lock.json` and `node_moduels` and clean installed from `npm install` but now when I try `npm start` locally, i get the same error (before it worked locally really well)

Comment: Well, I hope you have a backup.

Comment: I have copies of this repository in the same folder. Can it be a reason for this error?

Comment: Unclear.  But I have no more time to give.  Suggest making sure you have a backup.  Simplification is always a good thing.